# Using DOMDocument Validate() on XML Causes Infinite Load

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have an extremely simple implementation that pulls in a test bit of XML and attempts to validate it using DOMDocument. In testing, it's able to get through the LoadHTML() call fine, but as soon as I try and run validate(), the browser hangs forever and doesn't load. Here's the code:

```
$content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><mainElement></mainElement>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->LoadHTML($content);

if (!$dom->validate()) {
    echo 'fail';
} else {
    echo 'success!';
}
```

Comment: So why do you want to parse XML with `loadHTML` and not with `loadXML`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that if you want to validate content loaded with `loadHTML`, you need `DOCTYPE` [declaration](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/own-dtd.html) (without it, you get an infinitive loop). For example, following code works and prints `fail`

```
$content = "
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    Content of the document......
    </body>
    </html>
";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

if (!$dom->validate()) {
    echo 'fail';
} else {
    echo 'success!';
}
```

**For XML** it's more tolerant (it works even you didn't declare `dtd` but it returns false). In your case, you might use `loadXML` method and your code will print `fail`.

Tested with `php 7.0.13`.

Comment: This makes sense, and I've switched over to using loadXML as suggested and get 'fail' now. I'm curious, though, why this fails to validate? I was expecting to get a success back.

Comment: @carbide20 It's failing because you haven't specified `dtd`. Validation is the process of checking if your xml is based on your `dtd`. Check https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd.asp out.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you for explaining this and taking the time to answer!